# Sitecore indexing Boost Rule based on search term

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

How exactly do boost rules work for page items in context to search results? Ideally I would like a rule on a page that is essentially:

Condition: When search term is 'A'

Action:    Boost score to 10

The closest thing I have found is this [blog post](https://blog.vutborg.dk/2014/05/24/adding-personalization-rules-without-modifying-files/) about testing the query parameter via the 'when script returns true' condition but am having no luck in Sitecore 8. Thanks for any ideas.